# Ng-repeat, first item with different directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I got the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in placeholders" square class="set-holder {{i.class}}" droppable="{{i.type}}"></div>
```

How I make the first item has the directive `bigsquare`, while the others have just `square`.

I've tried:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in placeholders" {{= $first ? 'big' : ''}}square class="set-holder {{i.class}}" droppable="{{i.type}}"></div>
```

but sadly I the result is:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in placeholders" {{= $first ? 'big' : ''}}square class="set-holder test" droppable="3"></div>
```

a.k.a. the binding don't get compiled.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` as follows:

```js
angular.module('example', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [1, 2, 3];
  })
  .directive('big', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.css('font-size', '30px');
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="example" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat-start="item in items" ng-if="$first" big>
    big item {{item}}
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat-end ng-if="!$first">
    item {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The documentation can be found under [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Answer (score 3):

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nicolasmoise/xLfmK/2/.

You can create one directive to which you pass a condition. Depending on that condition it will either display the square or the big-square as such.

```
         <div ng-repeat="repeat in repeater" condition="$first" square></div>
```

**Note**
If you don't want to alter the directives you're already made, you can always have `square` be a master directive that calls the other two.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using another `<div>` inside of your `<li>`, you should be able to get away with doing conditional blocks of `<div>` using `ng-if="$index == ??"`.

Maybe something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in placeholders">
  <div bigsquare class="set-holder {{i.class}}" droppable="{{i.type}}" ng-if="$index == 0">
    ...
  </div>
  <div mediumsquare class="set-holder {{i.class}}" droppable="{{i.type}}" ng-if="$index == 1">
    ...
  </div>
  <div square class="set-holder {{i.class}}" droppable="{{i.type}}" ng-if="$index > 1">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

It's a little more verbose, but it nicely separates out the templates so that you can have them pretty independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- Here is a code sample which I used in one of my angularjs ionic apps.  -->
<!-- Regular ng-repeat -->
<!-- ng-if="$first" to determine <input focus-input> or not -->
<ion-item class="item item-input item-stacked-label" ng-repeat="input in template.inputs">
  <label class="input-label bh-dark" for="{{input.id}}">{{input.title}}</label>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="bh-left">
      <input ng-if="$first" focus-input id="{{input.id}}" type="{{input.type}}" placeholder="{{input.choices[0]}}" ng-model="input.answer">
      <input ng-if="!$first" id="{{input.id}}" type="{{input.type}}" placeholder="{{input.choices[0]}}" ng-model="input.answer">
    </div>
    <div class="bh-right">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-close-empty bh-icon-clear" ng-click="clearField(input.id)" ng-show="input.answer"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```